# Prediction interval for simple linear regression

Tags: regression, prediction-interval

I have been given two formulas:

$$
\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{n-p} (Y - X \beta)^T(Y - X\beta)
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{n-p} \sum ( y_i - \hat{\beta_0} - \hat{\beta_1}x_i)^2
$$

I also have

$$
\hat{\mathrm{MSE}} = \hat{\sigma^2}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{(x^* - \bar{x})^2}{\sum(x_i - \bar{x})}\right)
$$

where n is total number of people, p is number of paramters.

Are these formulas right for calculating MSE?

In my lecture notes, my lecturer as calculated $\hat{\sigma}^2 = 0.8$ and said thus MSE = 0.8. So does that mean I don't have to work out MSE if I have $\hat{\sigma}^2$?

Answer (score 2):

The first is the mean square error of regression, the residual sum of squares divided by its degrees of freedom - which is an estimate of the population variance parameter $\sigma^2$.  The second is an estimate of the mean square error of a single predicted response $x^*$.  So your lecturer was calculating the MSE for regression (& equating it to $\hat{\sigma}^2$), not the MSE for a predicted response.