# Running model without intercept term?

Tags: econometrics, intercept

I have the true model set as $y = b_0+b_1 x+u$. Now supposing that I'm running the model without the intercept term,

Under what circumstances would the coefficient term in the model (without the intercept term) be an unbiased estimator?

Personally, I like this model choice because the conditional variance of my estimator is the most efficient (between
the two model choices). Would this be a correct evaluation on my part?

Comment: Check the requirements/assumptions for linear model. If your data and model meet the requirement then you estimate of the regression coefficients is unbiased.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171125/correlation-between-ols-estimators-for-intercept-and-slope/171134#171134