# Independent variable is correlated with intercept, creating singularities

Tags: regression, logistic, intercept, singular-matrix

I am building a logistic model with about 20 variables. I have used the following code:

`fullmod = glm(cancer ~ B_SEX+BLINE_AGE_AT_BASELINE+B_BMI+B_chro+B_fdrc+B_hrt+B_LMET+
B_MET+B_FV+B_EDU+B_INC+B_MAR+B_EMP+B_sm_status+B_sm_y+CDHQ1_ALCOHOL_MYP+CDHQ1_HEI_2005_DERV+red.meat.w.g+red.meat_cat+location,family=binomial,data=all)

Summary(fullmod)
`
I got the following output:

[image]

I have investigated the correlation structure/linear dependencies of independent variables , found this:
[image]

So, Sex is correlated with the intercept, I found some explanation regarding this situation here [enter link description here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171125/correlation-between-ols-estimators-for-intercept-and-slope#)

But what is the solution, how I can remove this singularity

Comment: The link you included is unrelated. That's about the coefficients being correlated, not the predictors. Are you positive `B_SEX` has more than one value in it? This would occur if all values were the same. Are there any missing values in the predictors?

Comment: Yes, B_Sex has two values 1=Female with 34436 entry, 0=Male with 19493. and Yes, Other predictors have missing values, but not in the B_SEX.

Comment: If you run `with(na.omit(all), table(B_SEX))`, are there still two unique values? When missing data are present, all rows with missing data are removed by `glm()`, so the dataset that `glm()` fits the model on may not have the same levels as the data you submitted.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it now, after running your code, I got only one value in B_SEX, which is 1=Female. Then I have tried na.action=na.pass code, but it gives me the following error: "Error in glm.fit(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'x' ". apperantly "glm" will not use rows containing NAs. do you have any suggestion?

Comment: `glm()` cannot include missing values in the predictors or outcome. Search on this site for how to deal with missing values in regression. It's a big topic and the best answer depends on your purpose.