# Least Squares Regression - Error

Tags: regression, least-squares, fitting

In standard least squares regression, we find constants $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ such that the square of the average error, $\epsilon = y_i - (\beta_1 + \beta_2x_i)$, is minimized, and so the 'line of best fit' is given as:

$$y_{\textrm{avg}}(x)=\beta_1 + \beta_2x$$

Now, my question is, if you had to put associated error terms for each of the obtained terms (i.e. $\Delta\beta_1$ & $\Delta\beta_2$), what would they be? My guess is that for $\beta_1$, the 'error term' that I'm looking for would be the standard deviation $\sigma$, and so for the 'error term' for $\beta_2$ we would get the upper and lower bounds for the slope of the line within the 'wiggle room' defined by $\sigma$. [See picture]

[image]

Please give me some direction on this problem of mine if you can.

Comment: You might find the answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85560/shape-of-confidence-interval-for-predicted-values-in-linear-regression) of some use.