# What's the shape of confidence interval for linear regression estimated through TLS (total least squares)?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, total-least-squares

So, we know the shape of confidence intervals for vanilla linear regression estimated through OLS (ordinary least squares): [Shape of confidence interval for predicted values in linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85560/shape-of-confidence-interval-for-predicted-values-in-linear-regression).

In a univariate scenario I'm working right now uncertainty in both dependent and independent variables makes TLS (total least squares) attractive.

What would be the shape of confidence intervals for linear regression estimated through TLS?